# When are function arguments evaluated?

Tags: python, function, lambda, higher-order-functions

In this code snippet

```
def D(m, x):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    print(m)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    return x                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
print((lambda x: D(1, D(2, D(4, x))))(5))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
print("\n\n\n")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
print(D(1, lambda x: D(2, D(4, x)))(5))
```

We see the following output

```
4
2
1
5




1
4
2
5
```

Why are the output orders different? It looks like when the argument of D is a lambda, it is evaluated later, whereas if it is a function, it is evaluated first? How do I understand this?

Comment: Things should be more obvious if you ``print(m, x)`` instead of just ``print(m)``. In general, looking at the entire picture – via ``print``, a debugger, or similar – , instead of trying to deduce things when you don't understand them, works better.

Comment: I understand what is going on. I want to understand why it is going on. This is not the concern here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*All* arguments are evaluated at the time the function is actually called.

In the first `print`, we have a function defined by a lambda expression to apply to 5.

In the second `print`, we have a call to `D` that needs to be evaluated in order to *get* a function to apply to `5`.

---

What is `D`? It's basically an identity function that prints one value as a side effect before returning the other value. Let's rewrite it slightly:

```
def Dc(m):
    def identity(x):
        return x
    print(m)
    return identity
```

Take a moment to convince yourself that `Dc(m)(x)` is equivalent to `D(m, x)`.

Now let's rewrite your original examples using `Dc` in place of `D`.

```
print((lambda x: Dc(1)(Dc(2)(Dc(4)(x))))(5))
print(Dc(1)(lambda x: Dc(2)(Dc(4)(x)))(5))
```

It's a little easier to see if we pretend that Python as a function composition operator.

```
f ∘ g = lambda x: f(g(x))
```

`(f ∘ g)(x)` just calls `g(x)`, then passes the result to `f`.

**Important:** Keep in mind that any side effects of `g` will occur before the side effects of `f`.

Now let's rewrite our two examples using our new composition operator.

```
print((Dc(1) ∘  Dc(2) ∘ Dc(4))(5)) # print(t(5)) where t = Dc(1) ∘  Dc(2) ∘ Dc(4)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
print(Dc(1)((Dc(2) ∘ Dc(4))(5))  # print(Dc(1)(t)(5)) where t = Dc(2) ∘ Dc(4)
```

Since composition itself does not perform side effects, and function composition is associative, we can factor out the definition of `Dc(2) ∘ Dc(4)` to make it even easier to read.

```
t = Dc(2) ∘ Dc(4)
print((Dc(1) ∘ t)(5)
print(Dc(1)(t)(5))
```

Now it's easy to see what happens

1. In the first case, we *create* a function with a side effect of printing 4, 2, 1 before returning 5 to be printed.
2. In the second case, we *call* `Dc(1)` on `t`, outputting 1 immediately, before calling `t(5)`, which outputs 4 and 2 before returning 5.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you are directly calling the `lambda` function:

```py
(lambda x: D(1, D(2, D(4, x))))(5)
```

Since, you are calling it, value `5` is passed and the block inside the lambda gets executed in the order D4->D2->D` and thus 4,2,1, and 5 get printed. The second argument of the first call to D in the lambda is executed immediately as it is a call and not a reference to a lambda.

In the second case, you are calling normal python function and passing a call to lambda as a parameter:

```py
D(1, lambda x: D(2, D(4, x)))(5)
```

In this case, you are not calling lambda, instead you are passing a call to lambda which is essentially different, and that is why the order is from D1->D2->D4 and since x is passed to D4, the first value getting printed is 1, since the outer call is D1, and then when `x` is required in D1, the call to lambda passed to D1 as x gets executed, and the remaining print order is 4,2, and 5.

Answer (score 1):

All argument *expressions*<sup>1</sup> are evaluated before passing them into a call.

```py
>>> print(5)      # 5 is passed to print
5
>>> print(3 + 2)  # expression `3 + 2` evaluates to 5. 5 is passed to print
5
```

This also applies recursively: if an argument expression requires a call, the argument expressions to the nested call are evaluated, their result passed to the nested call, and then used to evaluate the outer argument expression.

```py
>>> #         abs(-2) => 2
>>> #     3 + 2 => 5
>>> #     5
>>> print(3 + abs(-2))
5
>>> print("The result of calling print(5) is", print(5))
5
The result of calling print(5) is None
```

---

Some confusion can arise because *functions* and *expressions* are closely related – colloquially, one might occasionally says that one "evaluates a function". Thus, it is important to distinguish between "an expression that evaluates *to* a function" and "an expression that involves *calling* a function".

```py
>>> print("The value of `abs(-3)` is", abs(-3))  # expression `abs(-3)` evaluates calling a function
The value of `abs(-3)` is 3
>>> print("The value of `abs` is", abs)          # expression `abs` evaluates to a function
The value of `abs` is <built-in function abs>
```

Notably, an expression that evaluates *to* a function just provides that function and does not evaluate whatever is inside that function. In fact it generally cannot: evaluating the body of a function usually requires arguments.

This distinction is important when dealing with "`lambda`"s: There are `lambda` *expressions* that can be evaluated to create a function, and there are `lambda` *functions* that are the result of such an expression. A `lambda` *expression* like `lambda x: print("lambda x got", x)` just evaluates to that function but does not call it.

```py
>>> lambda x: print("lambda x got", x)       # lambda expression => lambda function
<function <lambda> at 0x10f055670>
>>> (lambda x: print("lambda x got", x))     # nested lambda expression => lambda function
<function <lambda> at 0x10f055670>
>>> (lambda x: print("lambda x got", x))(5)  # called lambda expression => execution
lambda x got 5
```

---

To see the difference in evaluation between the two example cases, it helps to rewrite them to a) visually separate expressions and b) omit the common nested parts.

```py
print(
    (lambda x:
        D(1, ...)  # D(1 is inside lambda
    )(5)
)
print(
    D(1,                # lambda is inside D(1
        lambda x: ...)
    (5)
)
```

In the first case, `lambda x: …` is evaluated and the function immediately called via `(5)`. This *then* evaluates the nested calls in the body from the inside out: **4, 2, 1**.

In the second case, `lambda x: …` is evaluated and passed to `D(1, …)` *without* calling it; instead, the call `D(1, …)` is evaluated, printing its first argument **1** and returning its second argument `lambda x: …`. Only then  is the lambda called via `(5)`, evaluating the nested calls in the body from the inside out: **4, 2**.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, literals such as `5` and references such as `abs` are also expressions. They evaluate to their value and referent, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

1. print((lambda x: D(1, D(2, D(4, x))))(5))  = print((D(1, D(2, D(4, 5)))))
2. print: 4 execute:   print((D(1, D(2, 5))))
3. print: 2 execute:   print((D(1, 5)))
4. print: 1 execute:   print(5)
5. print: 5

output: -> 4,2,1,5

1. print(D(1, lambda x: D(2, D(4, x)))(5))
   ->  D(1, lambda x: D(2, D(4, x)))(5)):
   print(1)
   return lambda x: D(2, D(4, x)))(5)
2. print(lambda x: D(2, D(4, x)))(5))
   3...

Its not that they are executed differently, you have two different lambda functions in your code:

1. x -> D(1, D(2, D(4, x)))
2. x -> D(2, D(4, x))

Resulting in different outputs.

If you are interested in the theory behind:

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lambda-calculus/

It really helps to understand the execution of lambda functions, but is not that necessary for programming